# 7zip commands on Powershell can't be parsed?

Tags: powershell, debugging, 7zip

Here's the code

```
function New-BackupZip
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    Param
    (
        #File to be compressed
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [String]
        $File,

        #Password
        [String]
        $Password
    )

    Begin
    {
        [String]${Output-Filename} = "Backups_$((Get-Date).ToShortDateString()).zip"
        [String]$7zipParams = "-tzip -p$password ${Output-Filename} $File"
        [string]$7zipPath = "${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    }
    Process
    {
        & $7zipPath "a $7zipParams".ToString()
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

My error ALL THE TIME, no matter where I look into, it's that 7z.exe says "unsupported command":
[Unsupported command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v37vv.png)
[Testing the CMDlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgc7h.png)

But If I type it manually, of course it works:
[Manually works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9NRw.png)

So, what the heck is going on?
Is there something going on in the background of PowerShell that the 7zip exe file can't understand?

Comment: What does running just: `$7zipParams` return?

Comment: Try just `& $7zipPath a $7zipParams` and see if that works better for you. I think it's trying to parse all of your parameters as one parameter since it's all in quotes.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for the input, I've replied with the correct solution as it was not something related to the strings or similar, just PowerShell details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is something underlying PowerShell and Strings, and how it "sends" the string to a command.
The solution, use an array via the constructor:
`$ArrayOfParams = "a","-tzip","-mx=0","-mem=AES256","$passwordparam","$OutputFile","$File"`

Then, just use:
`& 7z.exe @ArrayOfParams`

That's the solution.

To expand a little on the "Underlying":

> "Generally speaking, this is how shells behave, not just PowerShell, so there's no documentation that specifically addresses what you've attempted. Command invocations (not just of external programs, though special considerations apply to them) are subject to argument parsing mode, which is described as part of the conceptual about_Parsing help topic"
> -mkelement0

Comment: Indeed, you need to pass the arguments (including option names) _individually_ to `7z`, not _as a single string_, as the latter is - by design - passed as a _single argument_. Note that passing the array directly (i.e. as `$ArrayOfParams`, without the splatting operator, `@`) works too, given that you're invoking an _external program_.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 , is there any documentation related to this?

Comment: Generally speaking, this is how shells behave, not just PowerShell, so there's no documentation that specifically addresses what you've attempted. Command invocations (not just of external programs, though special considerations apply to them) are subject to _argument parsing mode_, which is described as part of the conceptual [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode) help topic.